# ffmpegのエンコード時に起こるエラーについて

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffmpeg, raspbian

ffmpegのコンパイルに失敗していてIllegal instructionというエラーが起きていたんですが、以前このエラーについて質問した際に教えてくれた内容でコンパイルしなおしたところ上記のエラーがなくなりました！

しかしIllegal instructionでとまっていた処理が進み処理を見ていたら途中で

```
Failed to open segment 'streamfiles/stream000.ts'
```

とでてその後に

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?):
No such file or directory
```

とでました。streamfilesの権限の問題かと思って777にしましたが改善しませんでした。
このファイルの位置は `/usr/share/nginx/www/streamfiles` です。
これは権限以外に原因があると思うのですが、どういったエラーなんでしょうか？

機器はRaspberry Pi B+です。

実行したコマンドはこれです。

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -threads 2 -codec:v libx264 -s:v 1280x720
       -aspect:v 16:9 -b:v 256k -map 0 -f segment
       -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10
       -segment_list stream.m3u8 streamfiles/stream%03d.ts
```

実行結果は次のようになりました。

```
ffmpeg version N-75926-gce0834b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavcodec     57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
  libavformat    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 10156 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[libx264 @ 0xa4dd00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xa4dd00] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0xa4dd00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0xa4dd00] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=2 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=256 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[segment @ 0xa4cd20] Failed to open segment 'streamfiles/stream000.ts'
Output #0, segment, to 'streamfiles/stream%03d.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.3.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 256 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.5.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
[libx264 @ 0xa4dd00] final ratefactor: 40.16
```

Comment: ffmpeg を実行したのは `/usr/share/nginx/www/` ディレクトリですか? 例えば、`-segment_list stream.m3u8 streamfiles/stream%03d.ts` を `-segment_list stream.m3u8 /usr/share/nginx/www/streamfiles/stream%03d.ts` にしてみるとどうなるでしょうか(絶対パスを指定)。

Comment: ffmpegを実行したのは/usr/share/nginx/www/streamfiles/です。
絶対パスを指定して実行したらできました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

コメントの情報を参考に、実行時に出力先のファイルを**絶対パス**で指定することで解決しました。

```
ffmpeg \
  ...
    -segment_list stream.m3u8 \
    /usr/share/nginx/www/streamfiles/stream%03d.ts
```

---

この回答は [@社畜根性 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18186/ffmpeg%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e8%b5%b7%e3%81%93%e3%82%8b%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment16923_18186) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しています。